# How to I make text dark grey and then orange on hover for links?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have my text dark grey (#232323) and then on hover have it change to orange (#f66511) with an underline.

Looking at my jsfiddle, what am I missing in my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/brwb2r7a/9/

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper-landing">
    <div id="wrapper-icons">
        <div class="icons_row">
            <div class="icons_cell1 greyBoxOnHover">
                <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"><img alt="Gala" height="140" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/acq/ezj/acqezjKcM.jpeg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="140" /> </a>
                <p class="video-title rtecenter">
                    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">Wasington Apples:<br />Gala</a></p>
            </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper-landing {
    width: 916px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.rtecenter {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper-icons {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
}

.icons_row {
    height:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    }

.icons_cell1, .icons_cell2, .icons_cell3, .icons_cell4 {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    padding-top:15px;
    }

    .greyBoxOnHover:hover {
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
}

#wrapper-landing p.video-title {
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper-landing p.video-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper-landing p.video-title hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #f66511;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your hover written as `#wrapper-landing p.video-title hover` when it should be `#wrapper-landing p.video-title a:hover`

You were missing the `:` and the `a` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Hover is `:hover`, in the last CSS definition has to be

```
#wrapper-landing p.video-title a:hover
                                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper-landing p.video-title a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #f66511;
}
```

you forget about the `:`